# How can I use clojure.core/bean recursively?

Tags: clojure

So I think [clojure.core/bean](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/bean) is pretty close to what I want, but I'm working with a Java application that has nested beans, such that I end up with maps like this:

```
{:month-total 3835.0 :name "Jan's Meat Diner" :owners #<BarOwner[] [Lcom.fancypants.BarOwner;@1fb332d}
```

How, do I call `bean` recursively on a Java object so that I can get my imaginary `BarOwner` object to emit itself as a map, too:

```
{:month-total 3835.0 :name "Jan's Meat Diner" :owners { [:name "Jack"] [:name "Jill"] } }
```

### Edit 1

I have found that [`clojure/java.data`](https://github.com/clojure/java.data) and `from-java` is probably a better fit for this kind of thing than `bean`.

Comment: Be careful. `clojure.core/bean` is convenient, but insanely slow. Also if a getter does none trivial work you'll pay for it even if you don't need that particular value.

Comment: Yeah, I am curious about that, too.  I've been looking around and found out there's an [`org.clojure/java.data`](https://github.com/clojure/java.data) namespace with a more customizable `from-java` function, and I noticed there's another post  by Jay Fields that seems to address a more customizable interface: http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/05/clojure-converting-java-object-to.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's probably not an ideal answer to "how to use bean recursively", using more of the richer contrib libraries under the Clojure community's site did solve it.  Specifically

### [clojure/java.data](https://github.com/clojure/java.data)

provides simple recursive bean resolving, and can be configured to handle java types specifically in the hairy cases.  I'd recommend this to other people who want to use `bean`.

Comment: There are other options these days including: https://github.com/uwcpdx/bean-dip/ I'm the author but the readme summarizes some of the other libraries available.

Answer (score 0):

It is very tricky to find out what is a bean and what is not. This seems to do the trick for beans inside beans and properties that are lists. Probably you will want to add more classes to the `probably-bean?` function and perhaps some support for properties that are maps.

```
(defn probably-bean? [o]
   (and (not (coll? o))
         ((complement #{Class Long String clojure.lang.Keyword}) (class o))))

(defn transf [o]
    (cond
            (instance? java.util.List o) (into [] (map transf o))
            (probably-bean? o) (into {} (seq (bean o)))
            :else o))

(defn to-bean [o]
    (clojure.walk/prewalk #(transf %) o))
```

Comment: A cycle in the bean graph is also a great danger.