# Using destructuring-like syntax for java objects

Tags: clojure

I'm writing code whereby I have to traverse fairly complex nexted data structures implemented as Java classes, mainly POJOs. I like how I can use multi-level destructuring syntax when working with clojure maps or records -- I think it makes intent in the code clearer as opposed to navigating java object graphs using . or -> operations.

For example, I would like to be able to write the following code (made up):

```
(let [{registration-date :registrationDate              ; immediate field access
       {first-name :firstName                           ; destructuring nested object
        last-name :lastName
        email: email} :personal-data
       [first-order & remaining-orders] :order-history   ; destructuring nested collection
      } account]
  (... do something directly with symbols first-name, email, first-order, etc...))
```

The way I am doing it now is I have a set of 'bridge' functions that convert Java object of given type to a map. For example it may look like the following:

```
(defn map-account [account]
  {:registration-date (.getRegistrationDate account)
   :order-history (map bean (.getOrderHistory account))
   :personal-data (bean (.getPersonalData account)})
```

It works, but there is a lot of error-prone boilerplating (e.g. what if account.getPersonalData() returns null) and I wonder if there is a way to use syntax like map destructuring for Java objects that is more or less 'out of the box'?

Having thought about it, I'm not precious if it is actual destructuring or something that looks like it (e.g. some whacky macro) as long as it gives me the expressiveness comparable the former. Added bonus if it could be done in a lazy way, e.g. branches of the object graph are not traversed at all unless they are actually accessed.

**Edit:** It is possible to achieve something like this with `clojure.core.bean` or `clojure.java.data`, where the latter is recursive and the former isn't. I asknowledge that they may have a role to play, and in fact I am using bean in the example above.

My principal issue with using these approaches is that they are inflexible and don't allow any tweaks to the result. To give a few of examples where that might come very useful:

- One of the objects may be partially incompatible with JavaBeans convention
- There may be a need to flatten some parts of the hierarchy, especially when the underlying Java API is very idiomatic. It is a recurring practice in some APIs to have utility classes for pairs of objects that usually come together, e.g. [StateAndRef](https://docs.corda.net/api/javadoc/net/corda/core/contracts/StateAndRef.html). In Clojure it only makes the code more complex
- There is a limited control over how far the recursion should go. For significant object graphs it may be very costly.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/clojure/java.data?

Comment: Useful library. But I think java.data is for the other way around? From for example a clojure map to an object?

Comment: Oh wait you also have [`to-java`](https://github.com/clojure/java.data/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/data.clj#L115), it is just not mentioned in the README.

Comment: As I replied below, my main problem with bean and java.data is that it is impossible to customise the mapping. Some objects may be not fully conformant and it's simply nowhere to address it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is more about how to turn *objects* into Clojure data, than specifically about destructuring i.e. if you solve the conversion problem, the destructuring problem is already solved.

Clojure 1.10 defines [`datafy`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.0/src/clj/clojure/datafy.clj#L15) and [`Datafiable`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.0/src/clj/clojure/core/protocols.clj#L182). You can extend the `Datafiable` protocol for your types and have full control over how they're represented as data. Here's a trivial example using `java.net.URI`:

```
(extend-protocol Datafiable
  java.net.URI
  (datafy [u]
    {:host (.getHost u)}))

(datafy (java.net.URI. "http://clojure.org"))
=> {:host "clojure.org"}
```

It also defines [`nav`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.0/src/clj/clojure/datafy.clj#L30) and `Navigable`, which you could implement for lazy navigation e.g. to handle circular structures or data that's expensive to realize.

I think some combination of a `bean`-like function (to cover general cases) with `datafy` and `nav` should give you all the control/flexibility you need.

Comment: Yep, I’ve also stumbled upon this and started using it. It’s not ideal as pure destructuring would have allowed lazy lookups, whilst datafy has to pre-build the graph. If would be great if there was a protocol called, say, Destructurable, which would implement an equivalent of get-at with a key. Still, this is good

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `clojure.core/bean`?

```
(bean (java.util.Date.))
```

This will convert a Java object with getters and setters to the a Clojure map:

```
{:day 3,
 :date 8,
 :time 1578498930902,
 :month 0,
 :seconds 30,
 :year 120,
 :class java.util.Date,
 :timezoneOffset 0,
 :hours 15,
 :minutes 55}
```

Although it won't do it recursively, for that you can use `clojure.java.data`. This is describe in this question: [How can I use clojure.core/bean recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646684/how-can-i-use-clojure-core-bean-recursively)

Comment: I use bean in my current approach for some objects. My main problem with bean and java.data is that it is impossible to customise the mapping. Some objects may be not fully conformant and it's simply nowhere to address it. Another somewhat minor point is that it does not handle cycles, although it isn't a problem in my case